highcharts bar chart disappearing when upgrading from 10.2.1 to 10.3.1
I am currently trying to upgrade highcharts to the latest version, but ran into trouble.
I have a bar chart with the following configuration:
{
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                height: 70,
                pointPadding: 0,
            },
            title: {
                text: null,
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                visible: false,
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                min: startTime,
                max: endTime,
                visible: true,
                opposite: false,
                endOnTick: true,
                ordinal: false,
                minPadding: 0,
                maxPadding: 0,
                tickInterval: tickIntervalMs,
                minTickInterval: tickIntervalMs,
                reversedStacks: false,
                title: {
                    text: null,
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: mfTheme.colorPalette.n500,
                    },
                    // This makes sure that the times are displayed in the correct timezone
                    formatter() {
                        return moment((this as any).value)
                            .tz(institutionTimezone)
                            .format('LT');
                    },
                },
            },
            time: {
                timezone: institutionTimezone,
                moment,
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            tooltip: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: 24,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    pointWidth: 50,
                    groupPadding: 0,
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                },
            },
            series,
        }
}


and it renders perfectly fine up until version 10.2.1

When updating to Highcharts 10.3.1 however, the bar just dissappears, showing nothing. (no screenshot needed, it is just all white)
investigating the chart, it turns out, that all the  elements are heigh and width 0.
I am running this with highcharts-react-official.
I went so far as to look into the PR changes in the update notes, but could not find a single PR that would give me any clues as to what is actually going wrong on the new version.
how can I make the chart reappear?
codesandbox reproducable:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-demo-forked-s82pdf?file=%2Fdemo.jsx

Hi, as you use some variables that are not given in the code, could you please reproduce your issue in the online demo? You can start here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-demo-e1ue3

Great idea. Updated the issue

@magdalena this is however not the exact code as i am using typescript functional components.

Thank you for updating your question. I have analyzed it and added the answer.

The yAxis.min should be a number according to the API. I am not sure why this worked in previous versions; perhaps it was a typing gap that has since been fixed. The correct way of providing a minimal yAxis value would be, for example, a timestamp, just as you have in the case of yAxis.max.
Demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-demo-forked-5623sy?file=%2Fdemo.jsx%3A31%2C1
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min

Oh damn, so much wasted time for it's missing typescript support :( Thanks for your answer! do you know if there are typings available?

I’m not sure if I understand correctly. What I meant is that a number is the only correct type for yAxis.min, so a string date should be parsed to a timestamp, for example, before usage. TypeScript is fully supported.
